# How to bind external ip to Vagrant VM?

Tags: vagrant

I have external IP address. I added it to my `eth0` interface of host machine. I can successfully ping it. I want to run VM using Vagrant and set my external IP to it (I want to call my VM just like a simple VPS using this external IP address). I have next line in Vagrantfile for this:

```
node.vm.network "public_network", ip: myExternalIP
```

After my machine start I see `eth2` interface inside my VM with my external IP as `inet addr`. But I can't get access to any open port on my vm using this IP address. Maybe I don't understand idea of `public_network` in Vagrant. How to bind external ip to my Vagrant VM?

Update: As I understood vagrant set default gateway of VM to interface under NAT. Due to NAT packages cant be sent from VM to external world through bridged interface.

Comment: If you assign the IP of the host machine to the VM how will you access the host in that case?

Comment: I have additional external IP routed to my `eth0` host interface

Comment: Ok, then you need to remove that IP from eth2 at the host machine and configure it as "public network" in vagrant like [Alberick0 showed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36997613/171318)

Comment: eth2 is a bridged interface inside my VM

Comment: Then eth1 or whatever. Remove the ip from the host, assign it to a public network interface in the vm

Comment: It's already assigned to public network interface. But I haven't access to internet through this interface because it has no default gw.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working this way:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"
```

Comment: Does "192.168.0.17" external ip address?